# Youtrack deployment with docker: Could not listen on address 0.0.0.0 and port 443

Tags: docker, https

I'm trying to move Youtrack installation from one server (Windows) to another (Ubuntu). As now I'll use Linux I want to use docker to set up Youtrack instance.

My steps:

1. I've made a backup from the first server.
2. I've prepared new folders on the second server and run docker image:

   ```
   docker run --rm -it --name my-youtrack \
   -v /home/user/docker-services/youtrack/data:/opt/youtrack/data \
   -v /home/user/docker-services/youtrack/conf:/opt/youtrack/conf \
   -v /home/user/docker-services/youtrack/logs:/opt/youtrack/logs \
   -v /home/user/docker-services/youtrack/backups:/opt/youtrack/backups \
   -p 8080:8080 \
   -p 443:443
   jetbrains/youtrack:2019.2.56594
   ```

   Container is starts successfully:

   ```
   Starting YouTrack...
   * Configuring JetBrains YouTrack 2019.2
   * Made default base-url 'http://localhost:8080/' from hostname 'localhost' and listen port '8080'
   * JetBrains YouTrack 2019.2 runtime environment is successfully configured
   * Loading logging configuration from /opt/youtrack/lib/ext/log4j.xml
   * Redirecting JetBrains YouTrack 2019.2 logging to /opt/youtrack/logs/internal/services/bundleProcess
   * Configuring Service-Container[bundleProcess]
   * Configuring Bundle Backend Service
   * Configuring Configuration Wizard
   * Starting Service-Container[bundleProcess]
   * Starting Bundle Backend Service
   * Starting Configuration Wizard
   * JetBrains YouTrack 2019.2 Configuration Wizard will listen inside container on {0.0.0.0:8080}/ after start and can be
   accessed by URL [http://<put-your-docker-HOST-name-here>:<put-host-port-mapped-to-container-port-8080-here>/?wizard_token=VRjOG9ApYdo3UZky5xZW]
   ```
3. I can access Configuration Wizard via browser too `http://my-host.com:8080/?wizard_token=VRjOG9ApYdo3UZky5xZW` Where I select "Upgrade" option, and select my backup file. But in the next step (when I select 'https' tab), I get an error:

   > Could not listen on address 0.0.0.0 and port 443. Verify that the existing YouTrack instance is stopped and that there  are no other services that listen to the same address and port.

   [image]

And I can't understand why I get this error?

There is a result of netstat:

```
user@myhost:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      909/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1261/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      26920/docker-proxy 
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      24942/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1261/sshd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           909/systemd-resolve
443 is free on the host machine
```

The problem only with docker, when I run Youtrack by "ZIP' method - all is fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem from other side. I just added an nginx instance as reverse proxy in front of Youtrack docker container. So now my nginx manage https traffic and communicate with Youtrack docker container via http.